# Center Sub Nav Bar Items

Tags: html, css, zoho

I am trying to center the "subnav-content a" items.

Below is a snippet of the HTML Code.

```
<div class="navbar">
  <a href="https://creatorapp.zoho.com.au/zeroasbestos_outlook/compliance/#Page:Employees">Employee Details</a>
  <div class="subnav">
    <button class="subnavbtn">Employment Contracts<i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
    <div class="subnav-content">
      <a href="https://creatorapp.zoho.com.au/zeroasbestos_outlook/compliance/#Page:Employment_Contracts">Full-time</a>
      <a href="https://creatorapp.zoho.com.au/zeroasbestos_outlook/compliance/#Page:Part_time_Employment_Contracts">MV Part-time</a>
      <a href="https://creatorapp.zoho.com.au/zeroasbestos_outlook/compliance/#Page:Casual_Employment_Contracts">P&E Casual</a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Here is a snippet of the CSS I have:

```
.subnav-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  align: center;
  background-color: #35335d;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}

.subnav-content a {
  float: center;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

So far, I have two nav bars. A main nav bar that when the user hovers on a button it opens a subnav bar but the subnav bar items are stubbornly stuck to the left.  I would like them in the center. I have tried a few things already but it isn't quite working for me.

Comment: Css not available with `float: center;`, you can used a `text-align: center;` or with other css like `-webkit-box-align: center;-ms-flex-align: center; align-items: center;text-align: center;`

Comment: Hey, I tried your suggestions but they did not have the desired effect. Any ideas why  it isn't working? Usually these things would work, not sure what is going on.

Comment: Can you edit it with snippet run? Because I don't know fully your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it sorted. I had to wrap it in another div and create a custom column class.

```
.column {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 1px;
  
  }
  
  .column1 {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  padding: 1px;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

we don't have a `float` center. `float` is just `left` or `right`. You can use this

```
.subnav-content a {
position: absolute;
left: 0;
right: 0;

}
```

Comment: It centered the items in the subnav bar, but they were stripped of there colours and overlapped one another. Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: All the items in the subnav bar are centered and overlap one another.  The background colour of each item is stripped and only the white text is left.

Comment: You can use flexbox too, I am not influent in it but I know it will resolve your problem